# Visual studio debugging mode:how to go to the location of the next statement to be executed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

this should be simple but I googled it and I cant find any information. When debugging in Visual Studio,  how can I move to the location of the arrow that points to the next statement to be executed? I moved around and now I cant find it. there should be an easy way. Thanks
A.

Comment: try the code-map feature, which will give you a visual map of the code that has been called and what will be called and how its interconnected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click in source code (any file), choose `Show Next Statement`, alternatively it's shortcut `Alt + Num*`

Also, you could use `Alt + _` to go to where you previously

Comment: Ok, I feel real smart asking this, but how does one physically press `Alt + Num *`?  I see it in documentation across the webs, and it makes no sense to me..  Num Lock?!

Comment: Ok, found it somewhere..  If anyone else was wondering, it means `Alt + *` but the `*` located on the Numpad, not over the 8.  :P

Comment: In VS 2017, Show next statement is not available in the right click - context menu.... But the hotkey **ALT** + * (in the Num pad) still works

Comment: "Alt + _" ?;  "ctrl _"  you mean, I think; which takes you where you were just before now.